# How to put two data sources in the same listView?

Tags: asp.net

I have a search page get data from two sources:

1- my data base

2- web service function

How to put this two data sources in my list view?

Answer (score 2):

You cannot assign two datasources to a ListView. Therefore it is your responsibility to colate the two sources of data into on result set.

I suggest you use something like the [objectdatasource](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.objectdatasource.aspx) to return your result sets and merge the results before returning the final results to the listview.

Hope this helps.